# how to get number of row selected in datatable (r, shiny)

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, row, selection

I have a function that takes the row number (as in row 2 of 6) of a table. In my server, I have a datatable (based off of a selection I'm calling 'stuff' here) that allows single row selection. I want to be able to take the number of the row selected to put in my function. This is what I have in my server currently:

```
output$dt <- renderDT( 
    get_df(input$stuff),
    selection = list(mode = "single", target = "row"),
    server = FALSE,
    rownames = FALSE
  )

output$selected_row <- renderPrint({
    s <- input$dt_rows_selected
    if (length(s)) {
      get_member_extra_info(input$stuff, row(s, as.factor = FALSE))
    }
    })
```

Row() isn't actually getting the number of the row though (and doesn't work because it isn't a matrix). Does anyone know what I can put in its place?

EDIT: I had been having trouble figuring out what input$dt_rows_selected returns, and I guess that's all I needed. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I'm missing something --- doesn't `input$dt_rows_selected` have the number of the row selected in the table already? Wouldn't you just pass `s` in your function? If I'm not understanding, please give your shiny example and indicate further what you would expect in your `renderPrint` statement...

Comment: Yep Ben, that's all I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
table.row('.selected').index();//Returns the selected record number
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**